# How do I drag UIView elements and change position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drag, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm developing an iOS application which allows users to create form. Form has number of UIView elements stored in UIScrollView in stack. As far as editing goes, UIViews are supposed to change orders.

How do I achieve this? I want to drag any UIView component and move it anywhere in the form. For eg. holding third element will activate itself to move. Moving it on second element will replace its position. I'm using pan gesture to move UIViews. Now how can I know if tapped view reached on top of any UIView?

Comment: https://github.com/bvogelzang/BVReorderTableView for reordering the cell of UITableview

Answer (score 1):

There are few easy options for UICollectionViewController that can be easily handled by canMoveItemAt delegate method 
If you have a view controller you can try by following way:

```
import UIKit

class LoveProfileEditViewViewController: BaseViewController {
    fileprivate var longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer!
    @IBOutlet var theCollectionView:UICollectionView!
    public var items:[String]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let horizontalLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        horizontalLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        self.theCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = horizontalLayout
        self.theCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "SomeNibName", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Some Identifier")
        self.longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongGesture(gesture:)))
        self.theCollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
    }

    fileprivate func moveDataItem(_ sIndex: Int, _ dIndex: Int) {
        let item = self.items.remove(at: sIndex)
        self.items.insert(item, at:dIndex)
        self.theCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

    @objc private func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        switch(gesture.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.began:
            guard let selectedIndexPath = self.theCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: self.theCollectionView)) else {
                break
            }
            self.theCollectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)

        case UIGestureRecognizerState.changed:
            guard let selectedIndexPath = self.theCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: self.theCollectionView)) else {
                break
            }
            self.theCollectionView?.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))

        case UIGestureRecognizerState.ended:
            self.theCollectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
        default:
            self.theCollectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension LoveProfileEditViewViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 88.0, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10.0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10.0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return .zero
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return .zero
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
extension LoveProfileEditViewViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        //set boolean as per your need
        return true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        if sourceIndexPath.row > 0 && destinationIndexPath.row > 0 {
            self.moveDataItem(sourceIndexPath.row, destinationIndexPath.row)
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Some Identifier", for: indexPath) as! SomeNibName
        cell.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I mentioned objective-c

Comment: I'm using pan gesture to move UIViews. Now how can I know if tapped view reached on top of any UIView?

Comment: No need to think much on this case if you only need re-ordering thing. And sorry for swift as I am more into swift than objective-c :)

Comment: Cheers mate, I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your requirement, its, you want the user to be able to move/reposition some UIViews like drag-drop in parent view.

I would suggest you to use `collectionView` with its interactive movement enabled. If you want to use some library then you may try https://github.com/ra1028/RAReorderableLayout

Or for `UIView` drag & drop implementation you may check this
https://blog.apoorvmote.com/uipangesturerecognizer-to-make-draggable-uiview-in-ios-swift/

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I cannot use collectionView now as I have already written lots of code to handle form editing. I just need to rearrange UIView now which are added in UIScrollView.

Comment: @iPeter Correct!! But don't have the privilege to add comment :)

Comment: @HirenPrajapati Have a look at https://blog.apoorvmote.com/uipangesturerecognizer-to-make-draggable-uiview-in-ios-swift/

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTouch:withEvent:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vehicle.png"] 
forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Then you may move the vehicle wherever you want, by responding to the UIControlEventTouchDragInside event, e.g.:

```
 - (IBAction) imageMoved:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
 {
CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
UIControl *control = sender;
control.center = point;
}
```